# Anything other than variable in_array php

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm building a URL to send a $_GET variable in wordpress and need to determine if there is aready a "?" in the URL, in other words if the $_GET array is populated by anything *other than* the pair this script is sending.

Came up with the following which basically says, if there is nothing in the array we need to use "?", but if there's only one thing in the array and it is my_variable we need to use "?", otherwise ($_GET is populated so we're just adding to it so we) use "&".

But is there a way of saying, "If $_GET contains anything other than my_variable"?

```
if (count($_GET) < 1)
$get_divider = "?";
elseif ( (count($_GET) == 1) && (isset($_GET['mz_week'])) )
$get_divider = "?";
else
$get_divider = "&";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that wordpress, within which this plugin is designed for use, has it's own function for adding query arguments, which will add the "?" or "&" as necessary:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `strpos` on the Request URL:

```
if (strpos(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), "?") !== FALSE) {
    $get_divider = "&";
}
```

After the comments under this answer i came up with this solution:

```
   if (count(array_diff_key($_GET, array("mz_week" => 0))) == 0) {
       $get_divider = "?";
   } else {
       $get_divider = "&";
   }
```

It`s not that pretty, but does its job.

Comment: Then have 'else $get_divider = "&";'? Doesn't work because I still need the "?" IF there is one value in $_GET AND it is my_variable. Does that make sense?

Comment: Then whats wrong with your solution? Does it not work? Any error messages?

Comment: My solution is okay. I actually shortened it a little bit using an OR; `((count($_GET) < 1) || ( (count($_GET) == 1) && (isset($_GET['mz_week'])) ) )`. But it would be cool if there was a way to say IF ANYTHING BUT and use the "&" in that case. The code you offered is insightful, thought, for sure.

Comment: I have edited my answer with a possible solution to this. Is not the prettiest, but it works.